# How to install CUnit on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cunit

I am having a problem in installing CUnit on Ubuntu.

I tried

```
sudo apt install libcunit1 libcunit1-doc libcunit1-dev
```

after the command

```
CUnit --version
```

says command not found.

I searched and was unable to find anything.
Does anyone have a reliable solution?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

> To use CUnit framework in your project, you must install it first
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libcunit1 libcunit1-doc libcunit1-dev
> ```
>
> Then in your test.c
>
> ```
> #include <CUnit/CUnit.h>
> ```
>
> And finally, you must add the flag `–lcunit` to the gcc command (at the end)
>
> ```
> gcc  -o test test.c  -lcunit
> ```

From: https://mysnippets443.wordpress.com/2015/03/07/ubuntu-install-cunit/

NB: I have not tried this myself.

Answer (score 0):

CUnit isn't an executable, so `CUnit --version` won't work. It's just a library.

You can check installation by looking at the installation location. For me it installed in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcunit.*` (there are a couple files)